# Validation of textbox in javascript based on option selected

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Javascript to validate a text box based on the option selected but I am not able to process new http requests after processing this text box validation page. I don't understand the issue with this script.Code Seems to be Lengthier.I have a new frame which is used for new http request but after processing this page I am not able to open new http page in side menu bar of new frame. I find this problem when I dumped this code in our embedded device.Can u please help me in solving this problem?

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
  var txtBox=new Array("DestIP","Frms");
  var txtBox2=new Array("DestIP","Frms");
  function chkIPV4()
  {
    var x;if(document.getElementById(txtBox[0]).value.length==0){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[0]).name+" is not valid");document.getElementById(txtBox[0]).focus();return false;}for(x=0;x<1;x++){obj=document.getElementById(txtBox[x]);name=obj.name;val=obj.value;len=val.length;if(len<=15){var i;var Ascii1=0;var DecValue=0;var DecValueFlag=0;var dotcount=0;var dotflag=0;var dot=0;var Dec=0;for(i=0;i<len;i++){var ascii= val.charAt(i);if(i==len-1 && ascii =='.'){alert(name +" is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}if(ascii=='.' && dot ==1){dotcount++;dotflag=1;}else if(ascii=='.'){dotcount++;dot=1;}else{dot=0;}}if(dotcount!=3 || dotflag==1){dotcount=0;dot=0;dotflag=0;alert(name +" is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}for(i=0;i<len;i++){var ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);if(ascii<48||ascii>57){if(val.charAt(i)!='.'){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}}}for(i=0;i<len;i++){Ascii1=val.charCodeAt(i);Dec=Ascii1-48;if(Ascii1!=46){DecValue=(DecValue*10) +Dec;}else{if(DecValue<0 || DecValue>255){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}DecValue=0;}if(DecValue<0 || DecValue>255){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}}}}for(x=1;x<txtBox.length;x++){obj=document.getElementById(txtBox[x]);name=obj.name;val=obj.value;len=val.length;var i;var Dec=0;var DecValue=0;for(i=0;i<len;i++){var ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);if(ascii<48 || ascii>57){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[x]).name+" is not valid");document.getElementById(txtBox[x]).focus();return false;}else{ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);Dec=ascii-48;if(ascii!=46){DecValue=(DecValue*10) +Dec;}else{if(DecValue<1 || DecValue>16){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}DecValue=0;}if((x==1 &&(DecValue>999))){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}}}}
    obj=document.getElementById(txtBox[1]);name=obj.name;val=obj.value;len=val.length;var i;
    if(len != 0){for(i=0;i<len;i++){var ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);if(ascii<48 || ascii>57){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).name+" is not valid");document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).focus();return false;}}if(val<1 || val >50){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).name+" is not valid, Enter 1 to 50");document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).focus();return false;}}}
  function chkIPV6()
  {
     var x;for(x=0;x<txtBox2.length;x++){if(document.getElementById(txtBox2[x]).value.length==0){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox2[x]).name+" is not valid");document.getElementById(txtBox2[x]).focus();return false;}}for(x=0;x<1;x++){obj1=document.getElementById(txtBox2[x]);name1=obj1.name;  val1=obj1.value;len1=val1.length;if(len1<=39){var i;var Ascii=0;var IPV6DecValue=0;var charValue=0;var Coloncount=0;var doubleColonCount=0;var Colonflag=0;var Colon=0;var IPV6=0;var ascii = [ ];for(i=0;i<len1;i++){ascii[i]=val1.charAt(i);if(i==len1-1 && ascii[i] ==':'){alert(name1 +" is not valid");obj1.focus();return false;}if(ascii[i]==':' && Colon ==1){Coloncount++;Colonflag=1;}else if(ascii[i]==':'){Coloncount++;Colon=1;}else{Colon=0;}if(ascii[i-1]==':' && ascii[i]==':'){doubleColonCount++;}}if(doubleColonCount > 1){alert(name1 +" is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}else if(Coloncount <7 && len1<39 && doubleColonCount!=1){Coloncount=0;Colon=0;Colonflag=0;doubleColonCount=0;alert(name1 +" is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}else if(Coloncount <7 && len1<39 && doubleColonCount>1){Coloncount=0;Colon=0;Colonflag=0;doubleColonCount=0;alert(name1 +" is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}else if(Coloncount >7 || Coloncount<1){Coloncount=0;Colon=0;Colonflag=0;doubleColonCount=0;alert(name1 +" is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}for(i=0;i<len1;i++){var ascii=val1.charCodeAt(i);if((ascii<48||ascii>57) && (ascii<65||ascii>70) && (ascii<97||ascii>102)){if(val1.charAt(i)!=':'){alert(name1+" is not valid");obj1.focus();return false;}}}for(i=0;i<len1;i++){Ascii=val1.charCodeAt(i);IPV6=Ascii-48;if((Ascii>=65 && Ascii<=70) && Ascii!=58){charValue = Ascii;}else{if(Ascii<'A' || Ascii>'F'){alert(name1+ "is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}charValue=0;}if((Ascii>=97 && Ascii<=102) && Ascii!=58){charValue = Ascii;}else{if(Ascii<'a' || Ascii>'f'){alert(name1+ "is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}charValue=0;}if(charValue < 'a' || charValue > 'f'){alert(name1+ "is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}if(charValue < 'A' || charValue > 'F'){alert(name1+ "is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}}}}for(x=1;x<txtBox.length;x++){obj=document.getElementById(txtBox[x]);name=obj.name;val=obj.value;len=val.length;var i;var Dec=0;var DecValue=0;for(i=0;i<len;i++){var ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);if(ascii<48 || ascii>57){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[x]).name+" is not valid");document.getElementById(txtBox[x]).focus();return false;}else{ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);Dec=ascii-48;if(ascii!=46){DecValue=(DecValue*10) +Dec;}else{if(DecValue<1 || DecValue>16){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}DecValue=0;}if((x==1 &&(DecValue>999))){alert(name+ " is not valid");obj.focus();return false;}}}}
     obj=document.getElementById(txtBox[1]);name=obj.name;val=obj.value;len=val.length;var i;
     if(len != 0){for(i=0;i<len;i++){var ascii=val.charCodeAt(i);if(ascii<48 || ascii>57){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).name+" is not valid");document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).focus();return false;}}if(val<1 || val >50){alert(document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).name+" is not valid, Enter 1 to 50");document.getElementById(txtBox[1]).focus();return false;}}}
  }
  function chkFunc()
  {  
     var selectedIndex = document.f1.IPVer.selectedIndex;
     var optionValue = document.f1.IPVer.options[selectedIndex].value;
     switch(optionValue)
     {
        case "1":return chkIPV4();
                 break;
        case "2":return chkIPV6();
                 break;
     }
  }

  <FORM name="f1" action=" " method="post" onSubmit="return chkFunc();">

  <select name="IPVer" id="IPVer" tabindex="19"><option value="3">No Change</option><option value="1">IPv4</option><option value="2">IPv6</option></select></td></tr>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted.  Can you edit the question and add the 2 validation functions?  Also, what actually happens?  "Not able to process new requests" tells us nothing.

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Please find Complete JS Snippet which I Posted in my modified question